# How to get NON flickering loading div while typing AJAX (i tried)

Tags: jquery, ajax, fadein, fadeout

I hope you guys can help me with a loading `div` to be constant showing until I am done with typing the last letter. My output is now that it will flicker a lot while typing. I tried giving the loading `div` fadeout a time out but it's not really working (only on the first letters then after it still flickers a lot).

See my code please:

```
// Show loading overlay when ajax request starts
$( document ).ajaxStart(function() {
    if($("#keywords").val().length > 0) {
        $('.loading-overlay').fadeIn("fast");
    }
});

// Hide loading overlay when ajax request completes
$( document ).ajaxStop(function() {
    if($("#keywords").val().length > 0) {
        setTimeout(function() { $('.loading-overlay').fadeOut("fast"); }, 1000);
    }
});
```

I tried a long time to fix this with all kinds of solutions but nothing works. Let me know please.

Comment: Can you add problem code in https://stackblitz.com/, let me know once you reproduce it.

Comment: @Luckyy I will try its alot of code in between.

Comment: @Luckyy I will make it in jsfiddle. I saw that your website is for other programming languages.

Comment: yes Sure any online tool will work. Thanks

Comment: @Luckyy No i can't reproduce. The search input is made with AJAX and PHP. It's not really necesarry to make a jsfiddle about this right? Its just that the LOADING DIV flickers alot. I want it to be constant and after the last KEYDOWN/KEYUP the loading div will dissappear. You never saw a problem like this?

Comment: @Luckyy It needs like a delay and then at the LAST keyword it should stop.

Comment: In that case you should just wait for user to type, until he is finished typing. Then once typing is done, start loading.

Comment: @Luckyy Yeah i tried that with a KEYUP setTimeout of 2 seconds but it still stops yeah maybe because i put it inside a AJAX stop function. I will try again and again....

Comment: Please reproduce in a code snippet using the editor.

Comment: @Christian I said earlier that its not possible. Everything is with AJAX en PHP. And i dont think its necessary because its only about a DIV that need to STAY there without flickering when i type.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by putting the below code OUTSIDE the AJAX `beforesend:`. And it works now. It doesn't flicker. If i had put the below code in the AJAX it would flicker after a couple of keydowns.

```
jQuery(function ($) {
//to store the reference to the timer
var timer;
$('#keywords').keyup(function () {
//clear the previous timer
clearTimeout(timer);
//create a new timer with a delay of 2 seconds, if the keyup is fired before the 2 secs then the timer will be cleared
timer = setTimeout(function () {
  //this will be executed if there is a gap of 2 seconds between 2 keyup events
  console.log('last')
  setTimeout(function() { $('.loading-overlay').fadeOut("fast"); }, 0);
}, 1300);
});
});
```